# C# Authorization JWT token

Tags: c#, jwt, postman

I have an issue with Postman. When generating token truth swagger I get JWT. When checking the token in jwt.io it can read the token
[jwti.io success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6HXL.png)

But when adding it in postman it shows error 401.
[postman 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3qVI.png)

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

```
public class TokenHandler : ITokenHandler
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public TokenHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;
    }
    public Task<string> CreateTokenAsync(User user)
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));


        // create Claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress));


        //loop into roles of users
        user.Roles.ForEach((role) =>
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        });

        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key,SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
            signingCredentials: credentials);

        return Task.FromResult(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think, this is a problem with postman and not with your backend? Does it work with another client, that it would indicate a problem with postman?

Comment: Found the mistake,  was injecting bad token validations in Program.cs

Comment: Please post your answer below and accept it. Other users might stumble upon this question and find it useful.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with postman but everything to do with the token itself. Since you also already found out the answer please add a plenty detailed answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in Program.cs

```
//injected token validations by me
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters =
    new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
        (builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    });
```

On the last line `builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]`, i had added before
`builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"]`.  Changing it to Key fixed it